# Cannot access element in array converted from stdClass created by json_decode

Tags: php, json, stdclass

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = "2a123";
$arr[1] = "2123";
$arr["other_option"] = "2123";

var_dump($arr);

$arr = json_encode($arr);

$arr = (array)json_decode($arr);

var_dump($arr);

var_dump( $arr[1]);
var_dump( $arr["1"]);
```

The output of 2 last var_dump are NULL NULL, if we remove the 4th line $arr["other_option"] = "2123"; it'll ouput correctly, but I don't understand why!

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($arr);`?

Comment: TIP : try `json_decode($json, true)` instead of type casting using `(array)`

Comment: The TIP of diEcho works like a charm, but I still don't understand why, is it a PHP bug in type casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of type casting to array , set `true` in [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = "2a123";
$arr[1] = "2123";
$arr["other_option"] = "2123";
$arr = json_encode($arr);   
$arr = json_decode($arr,true);
var_dump( $arr['other_option']); // return 2123
```

[`working DEMO`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vCe28f)